# Problems with Kivy code in the background

Tags: python, kivy, apk

I have created a special alarm clock with Kivy. I know that this gui is not pretty but I will make it better later. However, every time i convert the Kivy code to an apk with buildozer, and then open the app and click the start button, then the app does not keep running in the background. Even if the app is open, but not opened directly, it does not keep running, even though it is essential for the alarm clock. I have changed the code a little bit, but I am not sure if its working that way. If so, then I do not know how I have to adjust the spec file accordingly, so that it generates an apk correctly.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

from android import AndroidService

class AlchemyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        # Create a label widget
        self.label = Label(text='Alchemy', font_size=50, color=(0.8, 0.4, 0.1, 1))
        self.layout.add_widget(self.label)

        # Create a start button widget
        self.start_button = Button(text='Start', font_size=30, background_color=(0.8, 0.8, 0.1, 1))
        self.start_button.bind(on_press=self.start_alarm)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.start_button)

        # Load the audio file
        self.alarm_sound = SoundLoader.load('alarm.mp3')

        # Start the Android service
        self.service = AndroidService('Alchemy Service', 'running')
        self.service.start('service started')

        return self.layout

    def start_alarm(self, instance):
        self.start_button.disabled = True  # Disable the start button

        # Call the "ring_alarm" method once after 6 seconds
        Clock.schedule_once(self.ring_alarm, 6)

        # Call the "ring_alarm" method 6 times at intervals of 15 seconds
        for i in range(1, 7):
            Clock.schedule_once(self.ring_alarm, 6 + i * 15)

        # Enable the start button after the last alarm is scheduled
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: setattr(self.start_button, 'disabled', False), 6 + 6 * 15)

    def ring_alarm(self, dt):
        self.label.text = 'Alarm!'
        if self.alarm_sound:
            self.alarm_sound.play()

        # Stop the Android service when the alarm is completed
        if dt >= 6 + 6 * 15:
            self.service.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AlchemyApp().run()
```